# Como enviar dados do formulário via _SESSION?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como posso enviar os dados do primeiro formulário para o segundo e depois enviar para o mysql ?

Tentei de tudo e quando envio para o banco de dados só chega os dados do segundo.
Irei colocar abaixo o meus formulários e o mysql .

Fico grato desde já .

formulário 1

```
    <main>

<div class="pedidos">
<form method="post" action="fazer2.php">
<table >
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" width="100">
         <span>Mesa</span>
         <input type="text" id="numero_mesa" name="numero_mesa">
         <label>
                    <span>Comanda:</span>
                    <?php
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id);
                     echo '<span>'.$row['ultimo'].'</span>';
                    ?>

                </label>
                <br>
                <br>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="280" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Refeição</td>
    <td width="70" bgcolor="#00BFFF">Quantidade</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha">Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha">Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha">Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Caldeirada de Tucunaré">Caldeirada de Tucunaré</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Peixe no Tucupi com Camarão">Peixe no Tucupi com Camarão</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Escabeche de Pirarucu">Escabeche de Pirarucu</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Escabeche de Tambaqui">Escabeche de Tambaqui</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
     <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Escabeche de Tucunaré">Escabeche de Tucunaré</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Tucunaré Frito">Tucunaré Frito</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Sardinha Frita">Sardinha Frita</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Jaraqui Frito">Jaraqui Frito</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Pacu Frito">Pacu Frito</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Filé de Pirarucu Frito">Filé de Pirarucu Frito</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Filé de Pirarucu a Milanesa">Filé de Pirarucu a Milanesa</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Guisado de Pirarucu">Guisado de Pirarucu</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Caldeirada No Tucupi com Camarao">Caldeirada No Tucupi com Camarão</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Caldinho de Tambaqui">Caldinho de Tambaqui</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Feijão">Feijão</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Arroz">Arroz</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Farofa">Farofa</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Vinagre">Vinagre</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Isca de Pirarucu">Isca de Pirarucu</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_refeicao[]" value="Bolinho">Bolinho</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_refeicao[]" size="7"></td>

</table>
 <br>
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Proximo" name="Proximo"> 
</form>
```

formulário 2

```
<?php
session_start();

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Criar a conexao
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "peixaria");
if($link->connect_errno){
     echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
     exit();
}

$sql= "SELECT MAX(m.id_pedido)+1 as ultimo FROM mpedido as m WHERE id_pedido ORDER BY m.id_pedido DESC LIMIT 1";

$resultado_id= mysqli_query($link,$sql);


$mesa = isset($_POST['numero_mesa']) ? $_POST[''] : '';
$_SESSION['numero_mesa'] = $mesa;

$pedido = isset($_POST['pedido_refeicao']) ? $_POST['pedido_refeicao'] : '';
$_SESSION['email'] = $pedido;

$bebida = isset($_POST['num_refeicao']) ? $_POST['num_refeicao'] : '';
$_SESSION['num_refeicao'] = $bebida;

?>

    <main>

<div class="pedidos">
<form method="post" action="relatorio.php">
<table >
    <tr>
   <tr>
        <td colspan="4" width="100">
         <span>Mesa</span>
         <input type="text" id="numero_mesa" name="numero_mesa">
         <label>
                    <span>Comanda:</span>
                    <?php
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_id);
                     echo '<span>'.$row['ultimo'].'</span>';
                    ?>

                </label>
                <br>
                <br>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Fanta Laranja 1l">Fanta Laranja 1l</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Fanta Laranja 2l">Fanta Laranja 2l</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Cola Cola 1l">Cola Cola 1l</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Cola Cola 2l">Cola Cola 2l</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Bare 2l">Bare 2l</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Fanta Uva">Fanta Uva</td>
        <td width="00"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Fanta Laranja">Fanta Laranja</td>
        <td width="00"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Sprit">Sprit</td>
        <td width="00"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Cola Cola">Cola Cola</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Cola Cola zero">Cola Cola zero</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Guaraná Antarctica">Guaraná Antarctica</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Guaraná Baré">Guaraná Baré</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Manga">Suco Manga</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Pessego">Suco Pessego</td>
        <td width="00"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Goiaba">Suco Goiaba</td>
        <td width="00"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Uva">Suco Uva</td>
        <td width="00"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Maracujá">Suco Maracujá</td>
        <td width="00"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Laranja">Suco Laranja</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Suco Caju">Suco Caju</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Agua Mineral">Agua Mineral</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Agua com Gas">Agua com Gas</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Cerveja em Lata">Cerveja em Lata</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="280"><input type="checkbox" name="pedido_bebida[]" value="Limonada Natural">Limonada Natural</td>
        <td width="20"><input type="text" name="num_bebida[]" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

</table>
 <br>
<button class="btn" type="submit">Fazer Pedido</button> 
</form>
</div>



    </main>
```

e o mysql

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Criar a conexao
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "peixaria");
if($link->connect_errno){
     echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
     exit();
}

       if($_POST)
{  
    $numero_mesa = $_POST['numero_mesa'];
    $pedido_refeicao = implode(', ', $_POST['pedido_refeicao']);
    $num_refeicao = implode(', ', $_POST['num_refeicao']);
    $pedido_bebida = implode(', ', $_POST['pedido_bebida']);
    $num_bebida = implode(', ', $_POST['num_bebida']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO mpedido(numero_mesa,pedido_refeicao,num_refeicao,pedido_bebida,num_bebida) VALUES('$numero_mesa','$pedido_refeicao','$num_refeicao','$pedido_bebida','$num_bebida')";
        $resultado_pedido = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
}


         $sql= "SELECT id_pedido,numero_mesa,pedido_refeicao,num_refeicao,pedido_bebida,num_bebida,data FROM mpedido ORDER BY id_pedido DESC LIMIT 1";
        $consulta = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

?>
```

Comment: Poxa allan... embora seja difícil para mim(pq naum sou expert) vou tentar ajudar...

Comment: muito Obrigado @MagicHat

Comment: Vamos tentar dividir o problema em partes....Quais são os forms que vc deseja trabalhar nesta ação ? Note que eu vejo 2 forms mas nenhum tem nome, eles possuem 2 actions diferentes 1-fazer2.php e 2 relatorio.php, o que exatamente deseja fazer ?Qui a pouco vou sair mas volto...

Comment: elas são Fazer.php e fazer2.php e no relatorio envia para o mysql e lista para mostrar na tela .

Comment: Certo, e onde está o Fazer.php ?

Comment: @MagicHat é o primeiro código . o segundo é fazer2.php e o terceiro é o relatorio.php

Comment: Quais dados vc deseja enviar do 1º para o 2º ? e onde deseja receber esses dados no 2º form ?... Ou o que vc deseja é preencher o 1º aperta próximo, preenche o 2º e envia pro banco ?

Comment: bem desejo enviar os dados do form um para o 2 e do dois para o mysql , sendo que irei selecionar vários checkbox e input number

Comment: então, o que eu não estou entendendo é se vc quer mandar os dados do form 1 para o form2, como vc imagina que o form2 irá receber esses dados ? O form2 irá exibir os dados do form1? Não estou entendendo a relação do form1 com o form2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara eu acho muito mais seguro usar $_SESSION com openssl.
Eu guardo tudo em session e vou elaborando o formulário de acordo com o que tem na session assim posso ter vários formulaŕio em uma mesma página sem sair dela tudo usando $_POST como modo de envio e tudo isso é analisado com regex para cada campo e colocado em $_SESSION.
Um esquema de como eu faço:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION[NOMEDASESSAO]['contato']['status']) OR $_SESSION[NOMEDASESSAO]['contato']['status'] != 1){

if($_SESSION[NOMEDASESSAO]['contato']['nome'] == null){
Formulario();
} elseif($_SESSION[NOMEDASESSAO]['contato']['email'] == null){
Formulario();
} elseif($_SESSION[NOMEDASESSAO]['contato']['assunto'] == null){
Formulario();
} elseif($_SESSION[NOMEDASESSAO]['contato']['texto'] == null){
Formulario();
} elseif($_SESSION[NOMEDASESSAO]['contato']['erros']['texto'] == 1){
Formulario();
}else{
$_SESSION[NOMEDASESSAO]['contato']['ok'] = 1;
Formulario();
}
}
```

O Formulario() se monta de acordo com o desenrolar dos dados. Só se tudo estiver certo é que o sistema faz um novo formulário com o campo de captcha. Não tem problema se neste ponto a pessoa tenta mudar algo e clica enviar pois todos os campos passam pelas regex a cada apertar de botão.
Simples, rápido e fácil.
Uso isso ai na página de contato(não tenho e-mail de contato para evitar spams), de parceria e sigo o mesmo princípio para a página de login, de lembrar senha, cadastro e tudo que eu queira fazer puramente em PHP sem ter que usar Javascript.
Bons estudos garoto!

Answer (score 1):

Cara lhe recomendo usar Ajax com JQuery, função $.post(), é mais "bonito", caso não queire usar, faça o seguinte, da o action de formulario1.php para formulario2.php.
Dentro do seu formulario2.php terás $_POST disponível.
Faça isso:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Feito isso, pegue os dados do $_POST, assim:

> input type="text" name="nome" value="$_POST['valor']"

Agora nos inputs do seu formulario2.php basta chamar os valores.
$_POST['valor']

Agora dando o submit, vai pro mysql.
**Recomendo usar var_dump** no seu formulário2 para você se orientar :D

---

## -Edição geral, vou resumir

Este é o seu 1° formulário

```
<div class="pedidos">
<form method="post" action="fazer2.php">
```

Após dar o submit, você vai para: fazer2.php

```
//Dê var_dump no arquivo fazer2.php
var_dump($_POST); //irá mostrar os valores disponíveis do formulário 1
```

Agora no fazer2.php faça isso:

```
<input type="tipo_do_seu_input" name="nome_do_input" value="$_POST['valores_desejados_do_primeiro_formulario']">
```

- Agora o usuário vai preencher o formulário 2
- Dando o submit, **dentro do fazer2.php**, vai para seu código Mysql

**Observe: Eu sei que você quer uma session, mas não é recomendada (por mim :D) para isso, a minha dica é mais fácil. Até!**

Comment: não entendi muito bem como posso fazer com sua resposta .